# Supermarket queue programming problem from codewars

Tags: python, data-structures, queue

the problem is as follows:
There is a queue for the self-checkout tills at the supermarket. Your task is write a function to calculate the total time required for all the customers to check out!

***input***:
customers: an array of positive integers representing the queue. Each integer represents a customer, and its value is the amount of time they require to check out.
n: a positive integer, the number of checkout tills.

***output:***
The function should return an integer, the total time required
my code is

```
import math
def empty(seq):
    is_empty=True
    for i in seq:
        if i>0:
            is_empty=False
            break
    return is_empty
def checks(cust,n):
    if len(cust)==0:
        return 0
    if n==1:
        sum=0
        for i in cust:
            sum+=i
        return sum
    elif len(cust)<=n:
        return max(cust)
def queue_time(customers, n):
    if len(customers)==0 or n==1 or len(customers)<=n:
            return checks(customers,n)
    main_sum=0
    tills=[0]*n
    leng=len(customers)
    if leng>n:
        for i in range(n):
            tills[i]=customers[i]
    t_len=len(tills)
    main_loop=t_len
    while(main_loop<leng and not empty(tills)):
        least=min(tills)
        if least==0:
            least = min(i for i in tills if i > 0)
        for inner in range(t_len):
            if tills[inner]>0:
                tills[inner]-=least
        main_sum+=least
        if main_loop<leng:
            for fill_zero in range(t_len):
                if tills[fill_zero]==0:
                    tills[fill_zero]=customers[main_loop]
                    main_loop+=1
    return main_sum
print(queue_time([2,2,3,3,4,4], 2)) #should equal 9 but the result is 5 !
```

the output should equals 9 but mine is 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One helpful thing is to use the [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) data structure from python standard library, which can be easily used as queue (or stack).

```py
from collections import deque

def supermarket_queue(customers, n):
    queue = deque(customers)
    total_time = 0
    workers =[0 for _ in range(n)]
    while True:
        for i in range(n): # loop over self-checkouts
            if workers[i] == 0: # check for free self-checkout
                if queue:
                    workers[i] = queue.popleft()
            if workers[i] > 0: # checkout has work to do
                # reduce amount of work
                workers[i] -= 1
        # for live updates (i.e. debugging)
        print(f"t: {total_time}, checkouts: {workers}")
        # check for customers or busy self-checkouts
        if queue or any([w > 0 for w in workers]):
            # add one timestep
            total_time += 1
        else:
            # no customers waiting, no checkouts busy
            break
    return total_time
```

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do this with 0 imports and 5 lines of code.
You create a list of available tills, iterate over customer checkout times,
add to the first index and run sort on the list so the biggest int (Longest time in to checkout) is the last index.
Each iteration then adds the next checkout time to the first index as it is the next available till etc.
Then simply return the biggest number in the list.

```py
def queue_time(customers: list[int], n: int) -> int:
    tills = [0]*n
    for i in customers:
      tills[0] += i
      tills.sort()
    return max(tills)
```

The above is fine for small number of queues and customers but slightly inefficient for larger pools, which is where `heapq` comes in.
It avoids sorting the entire list of tills for each customer. It instead uses a heap to efficiently find and update the till with the shortest queue.

```
import heapq

def queue_time(customers: list[int], n: int) -> int:
    tills = [0]*n
    heapq.heapify(tills)
    for i in customers:
        smallest_till = heapq.heappop(tills)
        heapq.heappush(tills, smallest_till + i)
    return max(tills)
```

- updated with typehints and heapq example

Comment: Brilliant. I struggled over this one for half an hour, knowing that all the solutions I came up with were too unwieldy. This is clever - the sort is ingenious.